# Authenticity of host can't be established in AWS ssh

Tags: amazon-ec2

When connecting to an AWS instance via ssh using -

```
ssh -i "key.pem" <aws-instance>
```

A message in the terminal reads -

`The authenticity of host <host> can't be established`

Now, generally I am ignoring it and going to the next step to add the key fingerprint and then successfully ssh into the server. But I am curious to know what are some of the potential pitfalls that this authenticity issue can lead to?

Comment: SuperUser: [Are SSL's default snake oil certificates truly snake oil as opposed to being genuine honest-to-good certificates?](https://superuser.com/questions/700170/are-ssls-default-snake-oil-certificates-truly-snake-oil-as-opposed-to-being-gen) explains it well: since the certificate isn't chained to well-known certificate authority, you can't know that the server is who you think it is (as opposed to someone else impersonating the server). As one answer says, these days it is trivial (and free) to create a trusted certificate, which will remove the trust issue (and the warning).

Comment: Hey @Amadan can you please put this in the answer? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment section by @Amaden:

> SuperUser: [Are SSL's default snake oil certificates truly snake oil
>   as opposed to being genuine honest-to-good
>   certificates?](https://superuser.com/questions/700170/are-ssls-default-snake-oil-certificates-truly-snake-oil-as-opposed-to-being-gen)
>   explains it well: since the certificate isn't chained to well-known
>   certificate authority, you can't know that the server is who you think
>   it is (as opposed to someone else impersonating the server). As one
>   answer says, these days it is trivial (and free) to create a trusted
>   certificate, which will remove the trust issue (and the warning).